# What is the correct word/term that needs to be before the names of the maker of the project?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing

I am doing a project with one other person, we have finished the project
and we are working on a cover page.

We are not sure what to write out before our names, we have thought
of a couple of options, but none of them seems quite right:

- Submitted by
- authors
- made by
- by

Note: Our work was to modify an existing piece work made by others, so something
like ``authors'' doesn't feel right.

Can someone please help us, what is the correct term to write out
before our names ?

Added: The project is the final project in a BSC in computer sceince, I am handing it in to a lecturer in the faculty who is my supervisor for the project.

Comment: I don't know the tags on this site yet, please feel free to edit them
or let me know about it and I will edit them myself. Thanks!

Comment: You still refer to yourselves as *author(s)*, considering that the modification of an existing work is in itself a project. A mere *By* should also work and is quite common.

Comment: The best place to ask, though, is writersSE; or even academiaSE, if that suits better.

Comment: However, without at least some idea of what the project, its starting point and deliverables, it will be difficult to come up with how your work (and thus you) should be described.

Comment: We discussed it over on Writers, and agreed to migrate it, although they will need some more information before they can give you good answers.

Comment: Hi Belgi and welcome to Writers.SE.  Can you add some information to this question about what your project is (class project? research proposal? hobby? etc), and where you plan to publish/submit it?  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Hi! I have added the requested information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Submitted by" might be your best answer. It obfuscates who the originator was (the authors/creators of the original work) and what you and your collaborator did, but the truth is, you are submitting this project (for what? term paper? publication? to a boss?). You can claim that honestly without worrying about who did what on the project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you've modified another work I"d say the best one would be to say:

'Project xx, (if appropriate), Modified by (names).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I feel that this format is not a good one for my case. I was working an a browser and not on an existing project of a person/small group. 'project chrome..' doesn't sound right to me

Comment: Modification *is* the project here, it seems.